# Is the phenomenon of liaison developed by dark L in British English in some areas?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation

There has been discussion about the dark L being heard as a vowel by L2 learners, though this view is often denied and corrected by L1 speakers, who point out that the dark L is indeed a consonant rather than a vowel. However, a study shows that the vocalization process is indeed completed in some areas in England (see page 13 on https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/4187965.pdf).

Any why, in the circumstance of a vowel following the dark L, is the dark L vocalized as well (in the u-areas on the map)? For example, is "all over" pronounced as "o over" or "o-l'over". If the former, is there any other mechanism that indicates the existence of two o's rather than one, for example by a glottal stop? If the latter, can I say that English in these areas has developed liaison as in French?

In French, liaison occurs as well after a pause caused by hesitation or thinking while speaking, e.g. "les... [1 sec. pause] s'enfants" where they keep the s after the pause. Does the after-pause-liaison also happen in a sequence like "a personal... [1 sec. pause] and..." in some British English accent?

In British English, the r in the end of "worker" is not pronounced, while in the sequence "worker of", it is pronounced. So how about if there is a short pause between the two words? Is it become "worker... [pause] r'of"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liaison phenomena vary a lot in English, even from context to context. A [2003 study](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/icphs-proceedings/ICPhS2003/papers/p15_1871.pdf) which named this particular phenomenon */l/-sandhi* said that:

> Coda (re)syllabification of /l/ is not subtle or flexible enough to condition the distribution of vocalisation. Prosodic, segmental and phrasal factors are all required.

Gimson's [classic tome](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=kXzMAgAAQBAJ) on pronunciation says under "Liaison" that:

> It is unusual for a word-final consonant to be carried over as initial in  a word beginning with an accented vowel.

... and under one example for "Juncture":

> *ill eagle* /ɪl iːgl/ : dark [ɫ] in word-final position; possibility of glottal stop before [iː]

In British accents with fuller L-vocalisation, the glottal stop would be even more likely.

In most *pre-pausal* positions in British English, liaison [is rare](https://www.persee.fr/doc/hel_0750-8069_1997_num_19_1_2573). That goes for the well-established, standard phenomenon of linking-R (hence "worker... of" is more likely to be [ˈwɜːkə # ɒv] than [ˈwɜːkə # ɹɒv]), and is even more marked for L-vocalisation. This stands in contrast to most varieties of French, where the liaison can happen with *enchaînement* [through certain pauses](http://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/HPSG/3/tseng.pdf), particularly through hesitations (although this is not necessarily considered very 'good' French).

Is there thus a intrusive-L in English, similar to intrusive-R? [It has been attested](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/518524/is-there-such-a-thing-as-intrusive-l-as-opposed-to-intrusive-r), but is more dialectally marked than L-vocalisation in general. Intrusive-R on the other hand is widespread and pretty much normal in the [colloquial English of most of England](https://www.persee.fr/doc/hel_0750-8069_1997_num_19_1_2572#hel_0750-8069_1997_num_19_1_T1_0045_0000), even crossing syntactic boundaries in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any resyllabification, liaison or glottal stop in American English. I hear they pronounce "LA" (the city) as if the second syllable has an l initially, and without any glottal stop. I feel that glottal stop is rarer in American English than in British English, while resyllabification/liaison more frequent. Is the feeling plausible?

Comment: Liaison _is_ common in speech when there are no pauses. Hence I'd expect "LA" to have a _clear_ linking-L in Received Pronunciation, a _dark_ linking-L in General American, and to have a linking-W in Cockney.